# If-else statement with same conditions as other if-else statement do not produce same output

Tags: vhdl

So I have to do an assigment where I have to write a counter which hase upcount mode = 1 -> increment = 5 and downcount mode = 0 -> decrement = -9. There is an invalid value of -69 which the counter should jump over.

There are also upper and lower bounds: -250 to 248.

To test our counter, a testbench was given.

I used the following if-else statement inside a process with the clk signal as sensitivity list entry.

```
if((cnt_intern + 5) <= 248) then
    cnt_intern <= cnt_intern + 5;
end if;


if(cnt_intern = -69) then
    cnt_intern <= cnt_intern + 5;
end if;
```

this did not work as it set the cnt_intern to -69, which the second if statement should prevent. I rewrote the if statement to the following:

```
if(cnt_intern <= 243) then#
    if(cnt_intern = -73) then
        cnt_intern <= cnt_intern + 10;
    else
        cnt_intern <= cnt_intern + 5;
    end if;
end if;
```

This time it did work and it jumped over the vlaue -69 directly to -64.

Anyone knows why? what is wrong with the first way?

best regards

Comment: The reason the second works but the first doesn't is because the second combines the if statements whereas the first is two completely separate if statements that aren't connected. 

You end the if statement and then you write another - See if you can work it out for yourself (it's a learning curve!) but if you're still struggling then come back and I'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: The first one doesnt prevent setting to -69, but waits until the cnt is set to -69 before checking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the observed behavior is that a signal assignment inside a process does not immediately change the signal value. Instead, a *transaction* is scheduled on the signal, which will take effect when the process suspends (i.e. when the end of the process or a `wait` statement is reached).

In your first example, if `cnt_intern` is -74 at the beginning of the process, the first if statement schedules as transaction, that means a change of the signal's value to -69 will take place at the end of the process if no other assignment schedules a transaction on `cnt_intern`. However, the actual value of `cnt_intern` stays -74 until the end of the process. So the second if statement will evaluate to false and do nothing. At the end of the process, the value of -69 is assigned to `cnt_intern`.

This concept seems confusing if you start working with hardware description languages, but it is essential.

You could use a helper variable to circumvent that issue and keep the code readable:

```
process(clk)
    variable v_cnt_intern : integer;
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        v_cnt_intern := cnt_intern;

        if((v_cnt_intern + 5) <= 248) then
            v_cnt_intern := v_cnt_intern + 5;
        end if;

        if (v_cnt_intern = -69) then
            v_cnt_intern := v_cnt_intern + 5;
        end if;

        cnt_intern <= v_cnt_intern;
    end if;
end process;
```

Other solutions are something like the code in your second example, which looks fine.

Comment: ok, get it. The variable cnt_intern actually was a helper variable, I just forgot to set it to the cnt signal at the beginning with cnt_intern := cnt;. I had to put the cnt_intern into the sensitivity list to make it work(otherwise i got a compiler error). Dont know why my code even works because I never set cnt_intern. I also used the rising_edge(clk) for edge dedection.